# Youtube API caching problems

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I use Youtube API to get video likes count and I need it in real time, everything was fine until now, but now likes count aren't updated in real time. Was this API cached? If yes, is possible to avoid this cache?

P.S: I use this API

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID?v=2.1

Comment: I want to Ans your question but youtube is banned in our country .... So i think any one else will help you